# Method like ng-change, but triggers after model update?

Tags: angularjs

I-m looking for a method for input fields which triggers on change, but which triggers after the model update.
The reason why I'm looking for this method is I have a rather complex web-page with many input fields that influence each other. And having a $watchGroup method and ng-change methods for each input which only sets flags if the user changed input on a field is not the best way to organize code. And I would really prefer a method like ng-change that triggers after model update, so that the flow of the code would be much clearer.

Does such a method even exists?

Regards, AK

Comment: Yep - `ng-change` is triggered after an update, you can send the model as a parameter to the function it invokes, and you don't need a `$watch` with it.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not the case. I have tested it and ng-change triggers before update.

Comment: @ak7483 - it triggers after... do you have a plunkr where this isn't the case?

Comment: Unfortunately I have the code at work, and I'm not sure if I can share it.
But I will try to create plunkr example tomorrow when I'm in office tomorrow.

Comment: @ak7483 does this solve your problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101697/angularjs-why-is-ng-change-called-before-the-model-is-updated

Comment: I did solve this problem, however it created a few new ones.
On the end I just solved the problem by calling callback withing the timeout function.