# AngularJS: ng-change called before an select element is changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

As far as I can tell, `ng-change` is called before `ng-model` is actually changed in a `select` element. Here's some code to reproduce the issue:

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    'use strict';

    $scope.value = 'a';
    $scope.displayValue = $scope.value;

    $scope.onValueChange = function() {
      $scope.displayValue = $scope.value;
    };
  })
  .directive("selector", [
    function() {
      return {
        controller: function() {
          "use strict";
          this.availableValues = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        },
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        scope: {
          ngModel: '=',
          ngChange: '='
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="ngModel" ng-change="ngChange()" ng-options="v for v in ctrl.availableValues"> </select>'
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
    <div selector ng-model="value" ng-change="onValueChange">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span>Value when ng-change called:</span>
      <span>{{ displayValue }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="demo.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If you run this, you should change the combobox 2 times (e.g. 'b' (must be different than the default), then 'c').

- The first time, nothing happens (but the value displayed in the text *should* have changed to match the selection).
- The second time, the value should change to the previous selection (but should have been set to the current selection).

This sounds really similar to a couple previous posts: [AngularJS scope updated after ng-change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19269130/angularjs-scope-updated-after-ng-change) and [AngularJS - Why is ng-change called before the model is updated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20101697/angularjs-why-is-ng-change-called-before-the-model-is-updated). Unfortunately, I can't reproduce the first issue, and the second was solved with a different scope binding, which I was already using.

Am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Comment: try ng-change="ngChange" instead of ng-change="ngChange()"? I think the ngChange() is making a call.

Comment: why would you want to wrap a `<select>` element? you start to box off all the really useful configuration you can do for no gain.

Comment: I suspect that It can be somehow related to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/31013435/2435473

Comment: @CallumLinington: This is just a simplified example to highlight the issue. A real example might be a directive with a `<select>` element and a few other elements.

Comment: @tsyu80 if it gets any bigger then i would try and bind controller values to it, i would use the event aggregator pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's good idea not to use the same model value in the directive. Create another `innerModel` which should be used inside directive and update the "parent" model when needed with provided [NgModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

With this solution, you don't hack the `ng-change` behavior - just use what Angular already provides.

```js
angular.module('demo', [])
  .controller('DemoController', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = 'a';
    $scope.displayValue = $scope.value;
    $scope.onValueChange = function() {
      $scope.displayValue = $scope.value;
    };
  })
  .directive("selector", [
    function() {
      return {
        controller: function() {
          this.availableValues = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        },
        require: 'ngModel',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        scope: {
          'ngModel': '='
        },
        template: '<select ng-model="innerModel" ng-change="updateInnerModel()" ng-options="v for v in ctrl.availableValues"> </select>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelController) {
          scope.innerModel = scope.ngModel;
          scope.updateInnerModel = function() {
            ngModelController.$setViewValue(scope.innerModel);
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <div selector ng-model="value" ng-change="onValueChange()">
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>Value when ng-change called:</span>
    <span>{{ displayValue }}</span>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34001183/878514).

Comment: Thanks! This works and makes a lot of sense. Also, thanks for editing my code blocks to be executable; I haven't played around with that yet.

Answer (score 1):

It's a digest issue.. Just wrap the `onValueChange` operations with `$timeout`:

```
$scope.onValueChange = function() {
   $timeout(function(){
       $scope.displayValue = $scope.value;        
   });
};
```

- Don't forget to inject `$timeout` in your controller.

... or you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754005/how-to-implement-an-ng-change-for-a-custom-directive) on how to implement ng-change for a custom directive

Comment: This seems like a viable solution, but @fracz's solution seemed more correct to me. (I assume his approach is what you were suggesting in your last line.)